# Removing the spaces between two characters a and e

Tags: spacing, positioning

I wanted to create a way to stick characters to gather in equations.
for example by writing

```
 $a \someorder e$
```

the output be exactly same as

```
$\ae$
```

fortunately for characters like a and e such command exists, but there is no command to stick characters bd, mm to gather.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rationale as well? `\ae` seems far more convenient than `a \someorder e`...

Comment: \ae is an example here. I wanted to type other similar cases like bd, mm, ... .

Comment: `\ae` may historically be related to `a` and `e` but to tex it is just a different character so your question is like asking how to stick `c` and `l` together to make `d` and tex can't do that. If you just want to kern them close then `$a\!e$` or `$x\!y$` might be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using the `\kern` directive.

I arrived at the kerning amounts employed in the following code by trial and error, aka "casual empiricism".

Incidentally, to my eye, the outputs of `a\kern-1.35pt e` and `\ae` don't look the same at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
ae a\kern-1.35pt e \ae
bd b\kern-1.5pt d
mm m\kern-2.7pt m
\end{document}
```